# Convert DateTime to human readable format (MSFT_MpComputerStatus class)

Tags: c#, datetime, wmi, windows-defender

Maybe this is a stupid question but I have a string with a date that looks like this: `20190516060354.000000+000` and wonder if I can automatically convert it into a date format like `dd-mm-YYYY hh:mm`.

**Important**: I don't want to parse the date manually.

The date comes from the WMIv2 class MSFT_MpComputerStatus => AntivirusSignatureLastUpdated

Comment: 'I don't want to parse the date manually' - what do you mean?
Take your string put it into a `DateTime` with `ParseExact` and re-format it with DateTime's ToString("dd-mm-YYYY hh:mm") method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use the appropriate System.Management Utility method

For *exactly* this scenario:

[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementdatetimeconverter.todatetime?view=netframework-4.8) method.

e.g. In PowerShell

```bsh
[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime('20190516060354.000000+000')       
Wednesday, May 15, 2019 11:03:54 PM
```

or C#

```cs
using System;
using System.Management;
System.DateTime dt = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime("20190516060354.000000+000");
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Answer (score 1):

## DateTime.ParseExact / TryParseExact

You have to parse it manually... using the tools .Net has.

You can do the following:

```
string inputDate = "20190516060354.000000+000";
DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(inputDate, "yyyyMMddHHmmss.ffffffzz0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string output = parsed.ToString(); // Or .ToString("dd-mm-YYYY HH:mm")
```

You can use the method TryParse if you are unsure about the format and log the errors to adjust it. Or use the overload that admits multiple formats in Parse/TryParse methods.

## More info

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

*I still have doubts on what the last 0 means or +000 with three zeros means.*